# How to correct the error in this code of selecting data from the database in php?

Tags: php, sql

I have written a code in php for selecting a value from a table in database. I have inserted a row with the value of $id and i wanted to select that particular row using that $id value from database.I have not written the insertion query in the below code.When I am giving the integer value directly in the select query, the firstname is getting displayed. But when the variable is given in the select query, it is not displaying the firstname. Can anyone help me on this ? The Code is given below :

```
<?php
    include('database.php');
    $id = rand(1,1000);                               
    echo $id;
    $sql = "select * from tbl_customer where cusid='$id'";
    $select = mysqli_query($con,$sql) or mysqli_error($con);
    $arr = mysqli_fetch_array($select);
    echo $arr["firstname"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try some debugging here:

```
var_dump($id);  // Check the value of your ID.

$sql    =  "SELECT * FROM tbl_customer WHERE cusid = '".$id."'";
$select =  mysqli_query($con,$sql) or mysqli_error($con);
$arr    =  mysqli_fetch_array($select);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);   // Check your fetched result
```

Comment: var_dump($id); is printing like this : int(983)

Comment: That's probably because your database doesn't have an entry with id = 983. There's nothing wrong with the syntax. Not sure what exactly you're expecting here. If there's no such id, the result will obviously be a blank array.